# How to change solr velocity homepage content?

Tags: solr, velocity

i currently have solr velocity up and running and working as it should be however velocity's homepage displays all the content of each indexed file one after another i was just wondering how to cut that down to just the first 5-10 lines of content for each indexed file ?

Comment: everything i could think of, tried going through all the velocity .vm files and editing the html and css to see if that would make a difference tried changing the solrconfig.xml file, i dont quite know what im looking for to be hinest

Answer (score 0):

Under $SOLR_HOME/conf/velocity you can find the velocity templates, just edit them (I'm not sure if you have to reload the core)